# MRSK successfully building/deploying app, but getting 404 page not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mrsk

Trying to get MRSK working with a hello world app, but traffic from Traefik does not seem to be getting to my app and all I get is a simple text `"404 page not found"`, which I believe is being returned by Traefik (it would render different from a Rails app, and not be just simple text).

When running MRSK, it builds and deploys the app (61.3s), after determining the container is healthy (app has a `/up` path).

If I run `# mrsk app logs` it shows successfully recent requests to `/up` and does not show any of my webpage requests.

If I run `# docker ps` on the remote server, this is the output and all seems good to me.

```
root@mrsk-test-3:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
575007c4d3bf   home/testrepo:HEAD_uncommitted_9594873ea15b59f4   "./bin/rails server"     14 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes (healthy)   3000/tcp                            home-web-HEAD_uncommitted_9594873ea15b59f4
92d5c2d95b1c   traefik:v2.9                                            "/entrypoint.sh --pr…"   4 hours ago      Up 4 hours                0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   traefik
```

**It seems that everything has deployed, but I've narrowed it down to seemingly traffic not going from traefik to my app. Any ideas and thanks in advance?**

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Ruby image as the base image
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.0
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION

# Install libvips for Active Storage preview support
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libvips && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/share/doc /usr/share/man

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT="1" \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES="true" \
    RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development"

# Install application gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile app/ lib/

# Precompiling assets for production without requiring secret RAILS_MASTER_KEY
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
# ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

# Expose port 3000 for the Rails server
EXPOSE 3000

# Set the initial command to start the server
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

Comment: You should provide the `config/deploy.yml` file with MRSK configuration

Comment: Did you find a solution? I having exact same problem.